A movie about human conflict, the army, and monsters
Approximate year and country of release: USA - somewhere between 2005 and 2010.
Main protagonist(s): A man and a woman (?)
Type of movie: Thriller/Horror.
Language spoken: English.
The movie was made in color.
I vaguely remember a scene in a supermarket, where a group of people get into a conflict and one of them gets shot (killed, if i recall correctly).
The movie has a very tense feel to it (you expect something bad to happen at any given moment)
I also remember a suicide scene in a car, after that the army comes into play.
I have been googling for about 4 hours now and i can't seem to find the movie im looking for.
Movies that are not it:
Resident evil - DeathProof - Strapped 

Is it this one perhaps (The Mist from 2007)?

Yes! it is! I have been browsing this site for quite awhile so i do find it strange this question never came up. Thanks alot! @Walt
